# MySQL Error Code: 1262. Row x was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, datatable

I need to load file content into a table. The file contains text separated by commas. It is a very large file. I can not change the file it is already given to me like this.

```
12.com,128.15.8.6,TEXT1,no1,['128.15.8.6']
23com,122.14.10.7,TEXT2,no2,['122.14.10.7']
45.com,91.33.10.4,TEXT3,no3,['91.33.10.4']
67.com,88.22.88.8,TEXT4,no4,['88.22.88.8', '5.112.1.10']
```

I need to load the file into a table of four columns. So for example, the last row above should be in the table as follows:

**table.col1:** 67.com

**table.col2:** 88.22.88.8

**table.col3:** TEXT3

**table.col4:** no3

**table.col5:** ['88.22.88.8', '5.112.1.10']

Using MySQL workbench, I created a table with five columns all are of type `varchar`. Then I run the following SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.txt'
  INTO TABLE `mytable`.`myscheme`
  fields terminated BY ','
```

The last column string (which contains commas that I do not want to separate) causes an issue.

```
Error:
Error Code: 1262. Row 4 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns
```

How can I overcome this problem please.

Comment: Extend the length of the column

Comment: There is unpredictable number of strings between brackets in the file. What I posted is a sample, but the strings inside the brackets are different in numbers. I want to treat them as a single columns for many reasons. Multiple columns for this field is not suitable to my case.

Comment: You are using  comma for separate  the  column so these  "unpredictable number of strings between brackets"  produce the error for importing  .. there some trciks for avoid this  ..  but not based  simply on Load data command  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks. You can post any tricks that can help even if not related to load command.

Comment: @user9371654  .. i have post an aswer  with a tricks I used  in similar case  ..

Answer (score 1):

Not that difficult simply using load data infile - note the use of a variable.

```
 drop table if exists t;
create table t(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20), col3 varchar(20), col4 varchar(20),col5 varchar(100));

truncate table t;

load data infile 'test.csv' into table t LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (@var1)

    set col1 = substring_index(@var1,',',1),
    col2 = substring_index(substring_index(@var1,',',2),',',-1),
    col3 = substring_index(substring_index(@var1,',',3),',',-1),
    col4 = substring_index(substring_index(@var1,',',4),',',-1),
    col5 = concat('[',(substring_index(@var1,'[',-1)))

;

select * from t;
    +--------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+
| col1   | col2        | col3  | col4 | col5                         |
+--------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+
| 12.com | 128.15.8.6  | TEXT1 | no1  | ['128.15.8.6']               |
| 23com  | 122.14.10.7 | TEXT2 | no2  | ['122.14.10.7']              |
| 45.com | 91.33.10.4  | TEXT3 | no3  | ['91.33.10.4']               |
| 67.com | 88.22.88.8  | TEXT4 | no4  | ['88.22.88.8', '5.112.1.10'] |
+--------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `(@var1)` is?

Comment: `@`var1 is a user variable(it could be called anything you like I chose `@`var1 to be consistent wth the documentation) - see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html for more on the use of user variables.

Answer (score 0):

In this case for avoid the problem related  with the improper  presence of comma you could import  the rows .. in single column table .. (of type TEXT on Medimun TEXT  ..as you need)

ther using  `locate` (one for 1st comma , one for 2nd, one for 3th .. )  and `substring` you could extract form each rows  the four columns you need

and last with a `insert select` you could populate the destination table  ..   separating  the columns as you need ..

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You have a *horrible* data format in your CSV file.  I think you should regenerate the file.

MySQL has facilities to help you handle this data, particularly the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` option in `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  The only caveat is that this allows *one* escape character rather than two.

My first suggestion would be to replace the field separates with another character -- tab or `|` come to mind.  Any character that is not used for values within a field.

The second is to use a double quote for `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`.  Then replace `'['` with `'"['` and `]` with `']"'` in the data file.  Even if you cannot regenerate the file, you can pre-process it using something like grep or pearl or python to make this simple substitution.

Then you can use the import facilities for MySQL to load the file.